# Pagination with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, pagination, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get some data from the following website. https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs

For every drug in the table, I will need to go deeply and have the name and some other specific features like categories, structured indication (please click on drug name to see the features I will use).

I wrote the following code but the issue that I can't make my code handle pagination (as you see there more than 2000 pages!).

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def drug_data():
url = 'https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text ,"lxml")
for link in soup.select('name-head a'):
    href = 'https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/' + link.get('href')
    pages_data(href)


def pages_data(item_url):
r = requests.get(item_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")
g_data = soup.select('div.content-container')

for item in g_data:
    print item.contents[1].text
    print item.contents[3].findAll('td')[1].text
    try:
        print item.contents[5].findAll('td',{'class':'col-md-2 col-sm-4'})
    [0].text
    except:
        pass
    print item_url
    drug_data()
```

How can I scrape all of the data and handle pagination properly?

Comment: all pages use almost the same url - with `&page=...` - so you can easily generate urls for next pages.

Comment: how ? have you an example ? thank you furas :)

Comment: normaly `url = https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs?page=" + str(page_number)`

Comment: you can use `for` or `while` loop and catch end of pages when it can't read page. Link to next page is also in button '>' on page so you can get it with `BeautifulSoup`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This page uses almost the same url for all pages so you can use `for` loop to generate them

```
def drug_data(page_number):
    url = 'https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/?page=' + str(page_number)
    #... rest ...

# --- later ---

for x in range(1, 2001):
    drug_data(x)
```

Or using `while` and `try/except` to get more then 2000 pages

```
def drug_data(page_number):
    url = 'https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/?page=' + str(page_number)
    #... rest ...

# --- later ---

page = 0

while True:
    try:
        page += 1
        drug_data(page)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
        print("probably last page:", page)
        break # exit `while` loop
```

You can also find url to next page in HTML

```
<a rel="next" class="page-link" href="/drugs?approved=1&amp;c=name&amp;d=up&amp;page=2">›</a>
```

so you can use `BeautifulSoup` to get this link and use it.

It displays current url, finds link to next page (using `class="page-link" rel="next"`) and loads it

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def drug_data():
    url = 'https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/'

    while url:
        print(url)
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text ,"lxml")
        
        #data = soup.select('name-head a')
        #for link in data:
        #    href = 'https://www.drugbank.ca/drugs/' + link.get('href')
        #    pages_data(href)

        # next page url
        url = soup.findAll('a', {'class': 'page-link', 'rel': 'next'})
        print(url)
        if url:
            url = 'https://www.drugbank.ca' + url[0].get('href')
        else:
            break
        
drug_data()
```

---

**BTW:** never use `except:pass` because you can have error which you didn't expect and you will not know why it doesn't work. Better display error

```
 except Exception as ex:
      print('Error:',  ex)
```

Comment: I added example which finds link to next page.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is very helpful !

Comment: So I am working on something like this, and it turns out the page doesn't load when you copy the URL and paste it on the address bar. It only loads by clicking the pagination button. What's the workaround?