# How to scrape specific categories from a corpus of news articles and store them in an appropriate file format for further classification + evaluation?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-science

Essentially what I'm trying to do is to parse HTML from a website

For 3 specific categories. I want to retrieve the title, short text snippet and category label of all of these articles for each month Jan - Dec 2020, and then store this information as an appropriate file format to perform text classification and model evaluation on.

I understand that you must use `retrieve` and then feed this to `beautifulsoup`. I just don't know how to ask for all of the articles under specific categories for each month on the link above, and then store this data together.

I would be so grateful for even a nudge in the right direction here!

Below is the code I've done so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("html")
page.status_code
articles = page.content

soup_article = BeautifulSoup(articles, "html.parser")

x = soup_article.find_all("a")
x
for month in x:
    month.find_all(class_="article")
    print(month)
```

Comment: Nudge: scrape all of the month links from the main page, then fire requests for each month link to get each page within the month, then scrape the articles from each page. See [Pagination with beautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47716519/pagination-with-beautifulsoup)

Comment: Thank you so much for your input, I genuinely appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the pattern of url construction you can generate many of the urls without scraping them. One needs to scrape the number of pages from the first page, for each month, to determine how many urls to generate for each month. You can of course scrape them if you don't want the `calendar` import, or simply use a dictionary with `{1:'jan', 2:'feb',.....}` and use that to return the month abbr to use in the url generation step

I use css :contains to target the desired categories. I use a function to extract a dataframe from each page and combine them into a final dataframe, then written to csv.

```
import requests 
import calendar
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

def get_data(soup, link):    
    rows = []

    for article in soup.select('.article:has(.metadata:nth-of-type(2):contains("Books","Music","Film"))'):
        title = article.select_one('a').text
        category = article.select_one('.metadata:nth-of-type(2)').text.replace('Category: ','')
        desc = article.select_one('.snippet').text
        rows.append([title, desc, category, link])
    return pd.DataFrame(rows)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    with requests.Session() as s:
        r = s.get('http://mlg.ucd.ie/modules/COMP41680/assignment2/index.html')
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        links = ['http://mlg.ucd.ie/modules/COMP41680/assignment2/' + i['href'] for i in soup.select('.list-group a')]
        urls = []
        results = []
        
        for number, link in enumerate(links, 1):
            soup = bs(s.get(link).text, 'lxml')
            pages = int(soup.select_one('.results').text.split('of ')[-1])
            #print(pages)
            results.append(get_data(soup, link))
        
            for day in range(2, pages + 1):
                urls.append(f'http://mlg.ucd.ie/modules/COMP41680/assignment2/month-{calendar.month_name[number][:3].lower()}-{str(day).zfill(3)}.html')

        for url in urls:
            df = get_data(soup, url)
            results.append(df) 
        
    final = pd.concat(results)
    final.columns = ['Title', 'Description', 'Category', 'Link']
    print(final.head())
    final.to_csv('data.csv', index = False, encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: This has been extremely useful thank you so much! I really appreciate the time you put into helping. I'm currently reading through it all, and I think this is what I was having trouble with!

Comment: You can replace using calendar with scraping all the links or simply use a dictionary with {1:'jan', 2:'feb',.....} and use that to return the month abbr to use in the url generation step.

Comment: Hi there again. For the parsed HTML data here, the apostrophe ' character seems to appear as missing values/red dots in the text or CSV file created at the end. Would you know how to prevent this from happening? Thanks :)

Comment: I will have a look today/tomorrow and get back to you :-)

Comment: Thanks so much I'd really appreciate that, only if you get the time, don't worry if not! Yeah basically it's just that both apostrophes and commas appear as missing values, and I can't use f.readlines() on the file due to the missing characters.

Comment: As missing or as other characters? Is there an example sentence to look for in a given link?

Comment: All commas and apostrophes appear as " â(followed by two empty squares)" in the resulting data frame and .txt file

Comment: Sounds like a possible encoding problem.

Comment: you mean It shouldn't be utf-8?

Comment: I will need to have a look utf-8-sig is usually good

Comment: Should I maybe use escape characters or something?